# Apache form based login catch bad credentials

Tags: html, apache, authentication, request-uri, setenvif

I have Apache 2.4 (httpd) on Red Hat 9.0. I have basic authentication working with ldap and a custom login form.

My httpd.conf has the following

```
<Directory /var/www/html/private>
    AuthType Form
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "/login.shtml?req=%{REQUEST_URI}"
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://DC:389/OU=Users,dc=x,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    Require valid-user
    AuthLDAPBindDN username
    AuthLDAPBindPassword pAsSwOrD
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
</Directory>


<location "/do-login.html">
    SetHandler form-login-handler
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "badlogin.shtml"
    SetEnvIf Referer ^.*req=(.*)&?$ req=$1
    AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation %{ENV:req}
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://DC:389/OU=Users,dc=x,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    Require valid-user
    AuthLDAPBindDN username
    AuthLDAPBindPassword pAsSwOrD
    AuthType form
    AuthName "Login"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
</location>
```

and I have a basic form in login.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/do-login.html">
  Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
  Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

What the `<directory>` directive does is send you to the page you originally requested after you login via the login.html page.

If you get the credentials wrong, the `<location>` directive sends you to badlogin.html, which is basically the same as login.html, but it has "BAD CREDS, Try again" in red font.

However if u get the creds correct here, it takes you to do-login.html ... 302 Found .. saying The document has moved `<here>` .. with 'here' being a hyperlink back to itself. Clicking on that link gives me the message "Method Not Allowed, The requested method GET is not allowed for this URL."

do-login has become the referrer here.

How can I get badlogin.html to send me to a legit page? I guess the original referrer is no longer known, so, /private/index.shtml would be a good enough successLocation.

Before I started to use `"?req=%{REQUEST_URI}"` and `"SetEnvIf Referer"` I was just using

`AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "/login.shtml"`
and
`AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "/private/index.shtml"`

So no matter what page you originally selected, you always ended up at "/private/index.shtml" after successfully logging in. I don't like that.
If you chose /private/pageA.shtml or /private/pageB.shtml, you always ended up at /private/index.shtml. With the above directives, if u choose /private/pageB.shtml, it takes you to /private/pageB.shtml after u login. But not if you make a mistake in the creds, and get them right the next try.

I have tried without success :

```
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "/badlogin.shtml?req=%{REQUEST_URI}"
```

Perhaps there is a way to conditionally set `AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation` ?

Just trying to account for the scenario that a user does not get creds correct on the first go.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue a few weeks ago, and for anyone interested, I just wanted to post how I did it.

I have the original `<directory>` directive which sends you to the `login.html` page for authentication, with the originally requested page attached as `%{REQUEST_URI}`

```
<Directory /var/www/html/private>
    AuthType Form
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "/login.shtml?req=%{REQUEST_URI}"
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://DC:389/OU=Users,dc=x,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    Require valid-user
    AuthLDAPBindDN username
    AuthLDAPBindPassword pAsSwOrD
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
</Directory>
```

I then have the original `<location>` directive, that processes the login.html form. If authentication is correct, you go to the page you originally requested, if not, you go to `badlogin.html`.

```
<location "/do-login.html">
    SetHandler form-login-handler
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "badlogin.shtml"
    SetEnvIf Referer ^.*req=(.*)&?$ req=$1
    AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation %{ENV:req}
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://DC:389/OU=Users,dc=x,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    Require valid-user
    AuthLDAPBindDN username
    AuthLDAPBindPassword pAsSwOrD
    AuthType form
    AuthName "Login"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
</location>
```

This directive processes `do-login.html`, which is not a real page. It is the `action` in the login.html form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/do-login.html">
```

I then added a new `<location>` directive.

```
<location "/next-login.html">
    SetHandler form-login-handler
    AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "badlogin.shtml"
    AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "/private/index.html"
    AuthFormProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://DC:389/OU=Users,dc=x,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    Require valid-user
    AuthLDAPBindDN username
    AuthLDAPBindPassword pAsSwOrD
    AuthType form
    AuthName "Login"
    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/
</location>
```

Previously, I had badlogin.html to be same as login.html, but with "BAD CREDS, Try again" in red font. This is still the case.
But I changed the `action` in the form:

```
   <form method="POST" action="/next-login.html">
```

This new directive processes `next-login.html`. Again, this is not a real page, it is the `action` from the form in badlogin.html.

If authentication is incorrect, you go back to badlogin.html. If correct, the originally requested page is lost by now, so I make you go to a hard-coded page, in this case, /private/index.html

This works fine for me. If anyone can make the new directive take me to the originally requested page, that would be much appreciated.